# Historic table in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activemodel

I'm new in Ruby On Rails, so, this is probably going to be a stupid question.
I need to create a table to save the history of the transitions of an attribute. The problem is that transition it's in a diferent class from the one where I'm creating the table. 
It goes something like this:

```
class Family::Parent 
     class Historic

     def add_historic
         #code
   end
end

class Family::Parent < ActiveRecord::Base

      def make_transition
          #code
      end
end
```

I know I can use something like ActiveModel::Dirty, but I have no idea how to do it, do you have any idea aout this ? 
Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you need something like [this](https://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions).

Answer (score 1):

easiest way is to use audited gem

SEE
https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited